# How to get substring of a string which don't have last two character of a string in java

Tags: java

Let's say i have following string.

```
   tempEventStartDate = 9:30AM
```

What i am trying to achieve is:

`9:30` in a different string.
    `AM` in a different string.

I got later one with this code -

```
     tempEventStartDate.substring(tempEventStartDate.length()- 2);
```

but i am bit confused that how to get 9:30 in a different string.

Any pointer will helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String newString = tempEventStartDate.substring(0,tempEventStartDate.length()- 2);
```

Comment: Just after posting this question i got answer in my mind...any way thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll` method to chop off the last two characters, like this:

```
String res = orig.replaceAll("..$", "");
```

This approach would work even for strings that have fewer than two characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
String prevStr=tempEventStartDate.substring(0,tempEventStartDate.length()- 2);

String aftrStr=tempEventStartDate.substring(tempEventStartDate.length()- 2,tempEventStartDate.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two overloaded function for substring

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
public String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)
```

So,your required string is

```
tempEventStartDate.substring(0,tempEventStartDate.length()- 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String tempEventStartDate = "9:30AM";

String timeValue = tempEventStartDate.substring(0, tempEventStartDate.length() - 2);
String timeType = tempEventStartDate.substring(tempEventStartDate.length() - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this as `Date` before? if yes you can skip the first line

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mmaa").parse(tempEventStartDate);
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(date);
String amOrPm = new SimpleDateFormat("aa").format(date);
```